# Windows Updates can be critical or recommended, but why?

Tags: windows, security, windows-update, updates, patch

I just wanted to know the difference is between Windows Updates being 'Critical' and 'Recommended'. And also what factors go into deciding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Critical updates (a.k.a., *security updates*) are those that [patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_%28computing%29) [vulnerabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulnerability_%28computing%29) which can be [exploited](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploit_%28computer_security%29) to do [bad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malware) [things](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_%28computer_science%29).

Recommended updates are those that aren’t strictly [necessary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_requirements), but may add features, improve performance (e.g., new drivers), or provide new functionality which may be come necessary to use newer software (e.g., .NET frameworks).

Comment: (Actually, I was going to mention optional updates like Bing Bar and Bing Desktop, but I figured it would be best to avoid it.)

Comment: I am sure we all have our personal understandings of those words, but in the case of Microsoft products, I think a pointer to the official definitions is essential. Witness, for example, Microsoft's use of the terms "boot partition" and "system partition", which is diametrically opposite the common usage. Notice that in the Microsoft document referenced in another answer, and here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824684, we get some pretty counterintuitive results.

Comment: `I am sure we all have our personal understandings of those words` If that were true, then this question wouldn’t exist. `in the case of Microsoft products, I think a pointer to the official definitions is essential.` You are always free to post your own answer with one. (Of course, the fact that the asker accepted one without such links, especially one another one with them already exists, seems to indicate that it served to answer the question they had just fine). Besides, like you said yourself, the official pages are confusing and self-contradictory.

Answer (score 2):

From [Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/understanding-windows-automatic-updating):

> **What types of updates will I get?**
>
> Windows Update categorizes software updates based on the update's importance. There are three categories for updates: important, recommended, and optional.
>
> **Important updates**. Important updates help keep your computer more secure and reliable, protecting your computer and your privacy. These updates include security and critical updates, as well as reliability improvements.
>
> **Recommended updates**. Recommended updates help keep your software up to date and your computer running at its best. If you selected Use recommended settings when you set up Windows Update, then recommended updates will be shown together with important updates. If you selected Install important updates only, recommended updates will be shown together with optional updates. Recommended updates include software updates and new or improved features.
>
> **Optional updates**. Optional updates include updates and software that you can install manually, such as new or trial Microsoft software or optional device drivers from Microsoft partners.

Answer (score 0):

As posted on February 4th, 2016 by Woody Leonhard, via his own website:

> "...I never install drivers from Windows Update (in the rare case where I can actually see a problem with a driver, I go to the manufacturer's web site and download it from the original source). If Windows Update has a patch but the box isn't checked, DON'T CHECK THE BOX. It's like spitting in the wind. I use Chrome and Firefox, and only pull out IE when I feel very inclined---but even if you don't use IE, you need to keep up with its patches...Yes, you read that right. I now ***recommed that you Win7 and 8.1 users only install Security Updates.*** For many months, almost all of the non-security updates Win7 and 8.1 customers have received are specifically designed to push them to Windows 10, or to increase Microsoft's ability to snoop on Win7 and 8.1 machines. No thanks."

What Woody Leonhard is saying here is absolutely correct. Microsoft is desperately trying to force users to Win10 (even inconspicuously) and it is up to you to pay attention and don't just indiscriminately download any update-------lest you become yet another victim of Microsoft's authoritarian concept.

Your PC is just that-------it is your (P)ersonal (C)omputer. The day we let them take that away from us is the day we give up on our own personal freedoms and allow the Evil Empire to control everything we see and hear and do-------Make no mistake about it-------The oligarch's are not simply satisfied with just keeping us in the dark-------they want even more control over our lives and Windows 10 is just another conduit to help them achieve this wretched goal of theirs.

> *"...The great initiative in this war is ours, the initiative to stop it, must be ours."*--Martin Luther King, Jr.

Comment: If you are going to use a driver in Windows other than one from Microsoft, I would stick with the OEM driver and go to the component manufacturer only if there was a problem with the OEM driver.